# How to use particles in Yafaray

Tags: particles, external-applications

So I'm starting to use Yafaray for my projects, but I noticed it doesn't support Blender's particle system yet.
I heard someone say that the best way to have those particle systems to render in Yafa would be to convert them all to meshes.

The problem is, for mesh-heavy systems like grass, for instance, it would hog tons of memory and crash to convert it to pure mesh (this won't happen using cycles or BI, since the particle system feature has ways to control the amount of children on viewport vs. rendered).

Is there an alternative workable way to have those particles on Yafaray?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, as of Yafaray 0.1.99 Experimental, with Blender 2.75a, the native particle system is now supported.